# Django how to allow user to set paginate_by value in profile

Tags: django, pagination

I allow my users to update their profile and set the paginate_by value for various ListView pages. How do I access this value within my view? Currently, the default is 20 as shown:

```
class CandidateListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'recruiter/candidate_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'candidates'
    paginate_by = 20
```

Instead of 20, I want to access that field in their profile. Do I need to pass it to view as parameter? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user has a related `Profile` model, with a field, for example:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paginate_by = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10)
    # …
```

You can override the [**`.get_paginate_by(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_paginate_by):

```
class CandidateListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'recruiter/candidate_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'candidates'

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        return self.request.user.profile.paginate_by
```

It might be safer to wrap this is a `try`-`except` in case the `.profile` does not exist:

```
class CandidateListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'recruiter/candidate_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'candidates'
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        try:
            return self.request.user.profile.paginate_by
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            return super().get_paginate_by(queryset)
```

Here you will fallback to `20` when the profile does not exists for that user.

You can return `None` if you do not want to paginate the result.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!